# Extracting values from dataframe columns and inserting them into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

[image: DataFrame]

I want the output to be:

[image: df_output]

I can do it looping over the original dataframe and adding data to a new dataframe but I have the impression there must be a simpler approach. I have tried pivot_table, grouping,query and dictionaries but with no results. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this site has rules about how questions should be asked, and this one does not meet them. As a new user, you really should read [ask]. Here, you have provided *links* to *images*. Both are frowned upon here, because links force readers to change page to understand the question and image prevent copy/paste. You should at least copy both dataframes as text (formatted as code) in the question itself.

Comment: Hi @KarlManz, welcome to SO. in general avoid pasting images because they cannot be use to reproduce your data. Your previous version was actually ok, where I formatted your table. Other users can take that and try. Any reason for switching to the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `'Owner'` to a category so that it will appear in the order after you pivot:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Owner':['John Doe','Woody Woodpecker','Bart Simpson','Ringo Star','Woody Woodpecker',
                           'John Doe','Donald Duck','Woody Woodpecker','John Doe','Bart Simpson'],
                   'Lot':['A%02d' % n for n in np.arange(1,11)]})
df['Owner'] = pd.Categorical(df['Owner'],categories=pd.unique(df['Owner']))
```

What you are missing is a column to enumerate the unique rows per group:

```
df['N'] = df.groupby('Owner').cumcount()+1

    Owner              Lot  N
0   John Doe           A01  1
1   Woody Woodpecker   A02  1
2   Bart Simpson       A03  1
3   Ringo Star         A04  1
4   Woody Woodpecker   A05  2
5   John Doe           A06  2
6   Donald Duck        A07  1
7   Woody Woodpecker   A08  3
8   John Doe           A09  3
9   Bart Simpson       A10  2
```

And changing this to the names you want, and you can pivot easily:

```
df['N'] = ['Lot'+str(i) for i in df['N']]
df.pivot(index='Owner',columns='N',values='Lot').reset_index()


N   Owner               Lot1 Lot2   Lot3
0   John Doe            A01  A06    A09
1   Woody Woodpecker    A02  A05    A08
2   Bart Simpson        A03  A10    NaN
3   Ringo Star          A04  NaN    NaN
4   Donald Duck         A07  NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I apologize for the way I asked the question and its formatting and I thank the replies which I am going to test right now. Best regards.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot!